# Extract field from array using DW 1.0 function

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a session variable called varIP1 which has a value like below: (It's mime type is application/java)

```
{abc={FedId=abc, Id=01FcLA, type=User, Profile={Id=02EmQA, type=Profile, Name=Analyst}}}
```

I am interested in extracting the first Id (01FcLA) from above using a function as given below:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var myLib = readUrl("classpath://dwlib/my-global-functions.wev", "application/dw")
---
{

    "Id": (myLib.idLookup(sessionVars.varIP1 ,$.Id,"Id") default null)
}
```

The global function that I'm using are:

```
%function validateLookup(lookupArray, key) 'true' when (lookupArray != null and IsNull(key) == 'false' and lookupArray[key] != null) otherwise 'false'
%function idLookup(lookupArray,key,value) (lookupArray[key][0][value] default '') as :string when (validateLookup(lookupArray,key) == 'true')  otherwise null
```

With the above code, "Id" is coming as null. Any modifications needed above?

Thanks.

Comment: What is `$.Id` supposed to be? That should not work outside a closure.
Unrelated to the question, why the functions use string literals 'true' and 'false' instead of boolean values true and false?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please correct the code for me? I need to retrieve the Id value from the sessionVars array. I can change the functions to boolean values as well.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the simplest approach if you know that your sessionVar will have the same structure:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    Id: sessionVars.varIP1..Id
}
```

Updated, since abc can't be hardcoded.

There's no reason to put `default null`. If it can't find the Id, it will be null. If you want to default to `""`, that would make a little more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The array structure will be the same but not the values. "abc" cannot be hardcoded.